# Get div content with jQuery for PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

**UPDATE**: Wow that was the fastest response ever and so many answers in minutes of each other. Amazing.  Ok here is what I am trying to do.  http://edvizenor.com/invoice33/

I want to edit this invoice on the fly but when I hit the BLUE BOX at the top I want to preview or see this content on the next page contained php var echoed out.

This blue box will change later to be a button at the bottom but for testing I am using it.

As you see it calls the ajax script but I need the edited content of the div to be sent a php var to I can echo it on the preview page.  If I can put it in a php var I do what I will with it on the next page. Does that make sense?  Thanks guys for your quick responses.

### OLD POST

Is it possible to get the contents of a `div` using jQuery and then place them in a PHP var to send via GET OR POST?

I can get the contents of the `div` with jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>   
       $(document).ready(function() 
       {
           $("#MyButton").click(function()
           {
               var htmlStr = $("#MyDiv").html();
           });
        });
    </script>
```

But how do I put the jQuery var in a php var. I need to do this by a BUTTON press too. This is not included in the code above. I need because the `div` file is changeable and when I hit UPDATE and send via PHP it needs to have the latest content.

Comment: Learn about ajax. Google ajax MDN

Comment: @metal_fan. It has nothing to do with `JSON`

Comment: @gdoron take a look at my answer

Comment: @metal_fan. I'm not a PHP programmer, but why do you need JSON to send data to the server?

Comment: @gdoron JSON is JavaScript Object Notation -- useful thing to exchange data between platforms, replacement for XML, as it faster, more elegant, and human-readable. For example, we need to send that user has changed his 'name', age' or whatever, so how do we know about success? The only one thing we need --- return in script TRUE and send back to JavaScript. Because both PHP and JS can proccess JSON, it becomes easier

Comment: @metal_fan. I know what is JSON. But you can send the data in every format you like. XML, querystring etc...

Comment: @gdoron but XML takes to load DOM tree, and XML-parsing is always slower. JSON is very common style to exchange data between platforms these days. JSON always used in modern AJAX applications, because it's very very fast

Answer (score 5):

According to your situation,
You are trying to send JavaScript variable to PHP.
The only common way to do this is to exchange in JSON format,

for example, suppose we have basic text editor

Jquery:

```
$($document).ready(function(){

   $("#submit-button").click(function(){
       $.post('yourphpscript.php', {
             //this will be PHP var:   //this is JavaScript variable:   
             'text'                : $("#some_text_area").text()

        }, function(response){
            //To avoid JS Fatal Error: 
            try {
                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                //get back from PHP    
                if ( result.success){ alert('successfully changed') } 
               } catch(e){
              //response isn't JSON
             }
         });

   }); 

});
```

PHP code

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 * So we are processing that variable from JavaScript
 */
if ( isset($_POST['text']) ){
  //do smth, like save to database
}


/**
 * Well if you want to show "Success message"
 * that div or textarea successfully changed
 * you can send the result BACK to JavaScript via JSON  
 */

$some_array = array();
$some_aray['success'] = true;

die( json_encode($some_array) );
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use ajax to send the value to your server.

```
var html = $('#myDiv').html();

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/SomeUrl/MyResource.php',
   data: JSON.stringify({ text: html }),
   success: function(response)
   {
      alert('Ajax call successful!');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [hidden form fields](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php) and use jQuery to set the value of the hidden field to that, so when the button is clicked and form submitted, your PHP can pick it up as if it were any other form element (using `$_POST`). Alternatively, you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to make an asynchronous request to your PHP page. This is probably simpler. Here's an example:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    var htmlStr = $('#myDiv').html();

    $.post("mypage.php", { inputHTML : htmlStr },
    function(data) {
        alert("Data returned from mypage.php: " + data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The thing you need is AJAX (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

The basic idea is to send a http request with javascript by e.g. calling a php script and wait for the response.

With plain Javascript AJAX requests are a bit unhandy, but since you are already using jQuery you can make use of this library. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for a complete overview.

The code on client side would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/script.php',
    data:'var=' + $('#myDiv').html(),
    type:'GET'
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response) // Your response
    },
    error:function(error) {
        console.log(error) // No successful request
    }
});
```

In your `script.php` you could do something like this:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];

// Do some processing...

echo 'response';
```

and in your javascript console the string `response` would occur.
In modern ajax based applications the best practise way to send and receive data is through [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

So to handle bigger datasets in your requests and responses you do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://example.com/script.php',
    data:{
        var:$('#myDiv').html()
    },
    type:'GET'
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response) // Your response
    },
    error:function(error) {
        console.log(error) // No successful request
    }
});
```

And in your PHP code you can use the `$someArray = json_decode($_GET['var'])` to decode JSONs for PHP (it will return an associative array) and `$jsonString = json_encode($someArray)` to encode an array to a JSON string which you can return and handle as a regular JSON in your javascript.

I hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Its possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#MyButton').click(function(){
   $.post('sendinfo.php',
    {
     data: $('#data').html()
    },
    function(response){
     alert('Successfully');
    });
  });
 });
</script>

<div id="data">Here is some data</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax for sending value to php (server).. here's a good tutorial for ajax with jquery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax.asp

Answer (score 1):

you should just use Ajax to send your variable.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'whateverUrl.php',
   type:'GET',
   data:{
       html : htmlStr
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX:

```
$("#MyButton").click(function() {
    var htmlStr = $("#MyDiv").html();

    $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {htmlStr : htmlStr},
      success: function(returnedData) {
         //do something
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$("#YourButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var htmlStr = $("#YourDiv").html();
    $.post(
        url: 'YourPHP.php',
        data: '{"htmlStr" : "'+htmlStr+'"}',
        success: function(){
            alert("Success!");
        }
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the data via XmlHttpRequest ("ajax") to your php page either via POST or GET.